# How can I get full Unicode font coverage for Gentoo Linux?

Tags: gentoo, fonts, unicode

I've installed over 159 new fonts, all that were possible in Gentoo mirror.

But even then, gnucharmap doesn't have:

- Arabic mathematical alphabet symbols 01ee00 1eebb

  - Arabic Extended-A ࢠ ࣾ
- Chakma

  - Meetei Mayek Extensions ꫠ ꫠ
  - Miao
  - Sharada
  - Sundanese᮫ ᮭ  ᮺ ᮿ (almost done)
  - Sundanese Supplement ᳀
  - Sora    Compeng
  - Supplementary    Private Use Area-B
  - Takri
  - Supplementary Private Use Area-A   (partially)
  - Rumi Numeral Symbols   (done)
- Aegean numbers U+10100 - 1013F (done , code2001 font)
- Avestan 10b00 010b3e (done)
- Bamum supplement 016800 (done)
- Brahmi 011000 01106f (done)
- cjk unified ideogram extension (done)
- cjk unified ideogram extension B (done) sunsim-extb.ttf font
- cjk unified ideogram extension C (done) babelstonehan.ttf universalia
- cjk unified ideogram extension D (done)
- Carian (done)
- Cuneiform (done)
- Cuneiform Numbers and Punctuation  (done)

  - Egyptian Hieroglyphs  Enclosed (aegyptus , gardiner) -done
  - Kana Supplement   done
  - Lycian  -  (done)
  - Lydian Letter A  -   (done)
  - Meroitic Cursive   (done)
  - Meroitic     Hieroglyphs    (done)
  - Arabian      (done)
  - Old Turkic   (done)
  - Variation   Selectors Supplement     (done)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10100/fontsupport.htm the following several fonts support U+10100: Code2001, EversonMono (and EversonMono Oblique), MPH 2B Damase, and Penuturesu. Note that Code2001 isn’t where it used to be, but it can be downloaded from [my Code2001 page](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/code2001.html). And you can add ALPHA-Demo and Quivira to the list.

Fileformat.info shows no support for U+1EE00, and I don’t know of any font that has it. The font used in the Unicode chart for the block is Uni1EE00Arabicmathsymbols (according to Adobe Reader), but I can’t find any info on it.

The situation looks similar for Avestan, Bamum, Brahmi – no support so far, in publicly available fonts.