# how to install unicode fonts in gentoo-based linux?

Tags: gentoo, fonts, unicode

this question:
[How can I get full Unicode font coverage for Gentoo Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55169/how-can-i-get-full-unicode-font-coverage-for-gentoo-linux)
gives the idea of what I want to do, but I don't know HOW to do that.

I wish to install all unicode fonts, because github shows me character codes instead of glyphs in website interface.

Comment: I'm a native Gentoo User... Let me research this and I'll get back to you with some comments or an answer. Welcome to U&L.SE

Comment: Let's Start Here with [UTF-8 on the Gentoo Wiki](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/UTF-8)  Finish that and report back.

Comment: how to list all available unicode fonts? is there any category for them? ls -1 /usr/portage/media-fonts
which fonts I should install ?

Answer (score 2):

You should just have to enable the portage use flag.

Add this line to `/etc/portage/make.conf`:

```
USE="$USE unicode"
```

Then run this as root:

```
emerge --update --deep --with-bdeps=y --newuse @world
```

Comment: No packages to rebuild, and still [] in Google Chrome, but correct in Firefox :(

Answer (score 0):

First, install `eix`, then

```
root # emerge $(EIX_LIMIT=0 eix -# media-fonts/*)
```

This will install every font you have available.